New windows don't come to front and focus after upgrade 24.04
In my previous setup, when a new application was started, or an existing application opened a dialog, the new window would come to the front and receive focus.
After upgrading to 24.04, this is no longer true. New windows are frequently invisible, and if they are visible, they don't have focus.
How do I fix this?
